# Help Finishing Proof Involving Collinearity and Cyclic Quads

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

**Problem:** Let $D$, $E$ and $F$ be the points of tangency between the incircle of triangle $ABC$ and the sides $BC, CA,$ and $AB$. Let $M$ and $N$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $B$ onto $CI$, and from $C$ onto $BI$, respectively. Prove that the points $M, D, E,$ and $N$ are collinear.

**So Far I have:**

Since $BMDI$ is a cyclic quadrilateral this implies that $\angle BMI = 90^\circ = \angle BDI$.

We know that $\angle MDI + \angle MBI = 180^\circ$. Denote $\angle MDB = \theta$. Then $\angle MBI = 90^\circ - \theta$.

**If we can only prove:** $\angle MDI + \angle IDE = 180^\circ$, then we can prove $M, D, E$ are collinear. (and then use a similar method to prove $D, E, N$ collinear).

$\triangle BDI \equiv \triangle BFI$ by HL so $\angle DBI = 90^\circ - \theta - \beta = \angle FBI$ ($\beta = \angle MBD$) and $\angle DIB = \angle FIB = \theta + \beta$.

Any help on what I should do next is appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN3B8.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $M,D,E$ are collinear. After that we can use the same idea and get that $D,E,N$ are also collinear and then $M,D,E,N$ are collinear.

First of al we have that $BIDM$ is cyclic because $\angle BMI=\angle BDI (=90°)$, so $$\angle MDI=180°-\angle MBI.\quad (*)$$

We then need to prove that $\angle IDE=\angle MBI$.

$1)$ By sum of angle in $\Delta BIC$ we get $\angle BIC=180°-\frac{\angle ABC+ \angle ACB}{2}=90°+\frac{\angle BAC}{2}$. But we also have that, by exterior angle theorem at $\Delta BMI$,  $\angle BIC=90°+\angle MBI$, so $$\angle MBI=\frac{\angle BAC}{2}$$.

$2)$ In the quadrilateral $ADIE$ we get $\angle DIE=180°-\angle BAC$ and from the isosceles triangle $IDE$ we get $$\angle IDE=\frac{1}{2}(180°-\angle DIE)=\frac{\angle BAC}{2}$$.

And then, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $\angle IDE=\angle MBI$ and backing to $(*)$ we get:

$$\angle MDI+\angle IDE=180°-\angle MBI+\angle MBI=180°$$

so, $M,D,E$ are collinear.

Comment: How did you determine that $\angle BIC - 180^\circ - \displaystyle\frac{\angle ABC + \angle ACB}{2}$ @Arnaldo

Comment: @rover2: sum of angles in $\Delta BIC$

Comment: so due to the fact that $\triangle BDI \equiv \triangle BFI$ implying that $\angle DBI = \angle FBI$ that means that $\angle FBI = \frac{1}{2} \angle ABC$ right?

Comment: @ you are right!

Comment: and what triangle are you using the exterior angle theorem to obtain $\angle BIC$? @Arnaldo

Comment: @rover2: $\Delta BMI$.

Comment: @Arnaldo How do you know ADIE is cyclic?

Comment: @Sorfosh: it is written in the solution. Because $\angle BMI=\angle BDI$.

Comment: @Arnaldo I am talking about the quadrilateral ADIE. You claim DIE=180-BAC which would mean ADIE is cyclic, where did you get that from?

Comment: @Sorfosh: Ok, sorry. It is because $\angle ADI +\angle AEI=90°+90°=180°$

Comment: @Arnaldo MY god that was obvious, hahah Thanks a bunch :)